# I am trying to add a for loop inside html, ? but the for loop shows error

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, frontend

I see a red squiggly line under {while add this for loop in my table, what am I missing here.

```
var cartHtml = `<table>
                  <tr>
                     <th> Item</th>
                     <th> Description</th>
                     <th> Price</th>
                     <th> Qty</th>
                     <th> Totall</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>`
                     ${for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
                       `<td>data</td>`
                     }}
                 `</tr>
                 </table>`
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: that (the red squiggly line) is a syntax error; you need to concatenate the html string you are building

Comment: I am trying to do that with backticks, can you please show how to concatenate exactly ?

Comment: Use a '+' to concatenate

Comment: ok trying that too!!

Comment: @Wimanicesir no concat needed with string interpolation, you can't concatenate `${}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to do a for-loop directly in innerHTML you can make a function of the loop and save the return data you want in another variable:

```
let loopdata;

const loop = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     loopdata+=`<td>data</td>`;
    }
    return loopdata;
  };
  
  var cartHtml = `
   <table>
  <tr>
     <th> Item</th>
     <th> Description</th>
     <th> Price</th>
     <th> Qty</th>
     <th> Totall</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  ${loop()}
  </tr>
  </table>`;
```